# StrictMode is throwing DatabaseObjectNotClosedException when using CursorLoader and leaving the current activity

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I'm using a very basic example where I create a `CursorLoader` with a uri from my content provider and populate a map. Everything works smoothly but when I leave that activity I get a `DatabaseObjectNotClosedException` thrown by StrictMode. I understand that the `CursorLoader` deals with the Cursor so I must not close it myself. So why does this happen?

This problem doesn't appear when using a ListFragment and I guess it's because in `onLoaderReset()` I do `adapter.swapCursor(null)`. But what should I do in my map fragment (or any other kind of fragment where I don't have a list) in the `onLoaderReset()` method? At the moment, I'm not doing anything because I don't hold a reference to the cursor returned.

Comment: I get exceptions also when using ListFragment. I really don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: Is this with the Android Compatibility Library or the native Honeycomb implementation?

Comment: this happens with Android Compatibility Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The revision 4 of ACL fixed these issues.